# how to install latest version of primeng 7.1.0

Tags: node.js, npm, angular-cli-v7

I'm using angular 7.1.0 and present i'm using primeng 6.1.6.How to upgrade my version to primeng 7.1.0.I tried some commands like npm install primeng --save.
but it is not working.and it is showing some error like this...

PS E:\srini_vision\skopiq-vision-web\angular> npm install primeng --save
npm WARN skopiqrpa@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN skopiqrpa@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN skopiqrpa@1.0.0 No license field.

npm ERR! path E:\srini_vision\skopiq-vision-web\angular\node_modules.bin\semver.cmd
npm ERR! code EEXIST
npm ERR! Refusing to delete E:\srini_vision\skopiq-vision-web\angular\node_modules.bin\semver.cmd: ..@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\semver\bin\semver symlink target is
not controlled by npm E:\srini_vision\skopiq-vision-web\angular\node_modules\semver
npm ERR! File exists: E:\srini_vision\skopiq-vision-web\angular\node_modules.bin\semver.cmd
npm ERR! Move it away, and try again.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\T5071\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2019-04-09T06_15_56_988Z-debug.log
PS E:\srini_vision\skopiq-vision-web\angular> npm run ng --version
5.6.0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can update like this..

1. uninstall the previous version as npm uninstall primeng
2. then reinstall it like npm install primeng

Comment: Thanks npm update primeng didn't work. I uninstalled primeng and installed primeng which took it to latest version.

Answer (score 6):

you can try npm i primeng@latest --save

or

npm update primeng